# "run file" is pop up in spyder but no result shows

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

Hi i am a beginner in python. i am trying to run through the following code on spyder but it returns the message "run file" and nothing pops up. would anyone help explain to me what is going on since the logic in my code should be alright. thanks for help in advance. the code is shown below.

```
def translate(phrase):
    translation=""
    phrase= "dog"
    for letter in phrase:
        if letter in "AEIOUaeiou":
            translation = translation +"g"
        else:
            translation = translation +letter 

    return translation

translate("dog")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Spyder, but it looks like the problem is that your script doesn't do anything with the return value from `translate`. Try printing it:

```
print(translate("dog"))
```